# HTML stylize a div like a rounded edge label

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am not very good at creating CSS Styles. I am trying to stylize a div like shown in the picture. Can someone help me with it? Either by telling what i need to do it or giving me the CSS for this. I have seen buttons and divs like this in many places but i have not found the CSS that makes it look like this.

[image]

Comment: Use [border-radius](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)

Comment: Please try something and then post it here. We can't help you until you try on your own.

Comment: Consider this: https://codepen.io/SgiobairOg/pen/pyXGWq

Comment: how about searching the web for this very basic thing you are trying to do instead of expecting us to give you / tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.btn{
border-radius:25%/100%;
border:1px solid #000;
background:#fff;
padding: 8px 15px;
font-size:14px;
}

.btn span{
font-size:10px;
padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">sometext
<span>X<span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.somebutton{
background-color: green;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 35px;
    color: white;
}
```

try this css

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```css
.divname
{
    border: solid 2px #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 35px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="divname">
Text Here
</div>
```

Comment: You should add `line-height: 35px` to center the text

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yeah but he didnt want to know how to do that, he just wanted to know how to make a rounded div container. So no need to over do it in the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete solution : (https://jsbin.com/jigupenihi/edit?html,css,output)

```css
.rounded-btn{
  background : #fff;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  min-width: 150px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Button</title>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <div class="rounded-btn">SOME TEXT <span class="close">X</span> </div>
</body>
</html>
```